# Immutable collection to "serialized" string

Tags: javascript, serialization, deserialization, immutable.js

I'm hoping to take an Immutable structure and stringify it into a file on disk such that it can be reevaluated into an equivalent structure. For example:

The collection:

```js
const obj = Immutable.OrderedMap({
  "key1": "value",
  "key2": [1, 2, 3],
});
```

The desired stringified version:

```js
import Immutable from 'immutable';

export default Immutable.OrderedMap([
  ["key1", "value"],
  ["key2", [1, 2, 3]],
]);
```

If we were sure we would only encounter Maps and Lists, we could just do `'fromJS(' + JSON.stringify(obj)) + ')'` but once you get things like `OrderedMap`s, `Set`s, etc. that approach will not work (loses order, makes everything a Map or List when rehydrated).

Is there an existing way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you find a proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an existing way, I've come up with the following:

```js
function stringifyImmutable(obj) {
  let prefix = '';
  let value = ''
  let suffix = '';

  if (obj === undefined) {
    value = 'undefined';
  }
  else if (obj === null) {
    value = 'null';
  }
  else if (
    typeof obj === 'number' ||
    typeof obj === 'string' ||
    typeof obj === 'boolean'
  ) {
    value = JSON.stringify(obj);
  }
  else if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    prefix = '[';
    value = obj.map((value) => stringifyImmutable(value));
    suffix = ']';
  }
  else if (obj instanceof Immutable.OrderedMap) {
    prefix = 'Immutable.OrderedMap([';
    value = Array.from(obj.entries()).map((item) => stringifyImmutable(item));
    suffix = '])';
  }
  else if (obj instanceof Immutable.OrderedSet) {
    prefix = 'Immutable.OrderedSet([';
    value = Array.from(obj.entries()).map((item) => stringifyImmutable(item));
    suffix = '])';
  }
  else if (obj instanceof Immutable.Set) {
    prefix = 'Immutable.Set([';
    value = Array.from(obj.values()).map((item) => stringifyImmutable(item));
    suffix = '])';
  }
  else if (obj instanceof Immutable.Map) {
    prefix = 'Immutable.Map([';
    value = obj.reduce(
      (items, value, key) => {
        items.push(`[\n${stringifyImmutable(key)},\n${stringifyImmutable(value)}\n]`);

        return items;
      },
      []
    );
    suffix = '])';
  }
  else if (obj instanceof Immutable.List) {
    prefix = 'Immutable.List([';
    value = obj.map((item) => stringifyImmutable(item)).toArray();
    suffix = '])';
  }
  else {
    prefix = '{';
    value = Object.keys(obj).reduce(
      (items, key) => {
        items.push(`${key}: ${stringifyImmutable(obj[key])}`);

        return items;
      },
      []
    );
    suffix = '}';
  }

  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    if (value.length === 0) {
      value = '';
    }
    else {
      value = '\n' + value.join(`,\n`) + '\n';
    }
  }

  return `${prefix || ''}${value}${suffix || ''}`;
}
```

This doesn't result in a very well formatted output (no indentation) but it seems to work. I'm using ESLint to format it, since my project is already using ESLint:

```js
// See https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api for documentation on the
// ESLint Node API
const engine = new eslint.CLIEngine({
  fix: true,
});

const results = engine.executeOnText(fileContent).results[0];
```

This would probably somewhat simpler if using v4.0.0-rc.9 which has `isImmutable()`.